# Scroll to bottom of page using Javascript or jquery with these conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to stimulate a web chat room for which the page needs to be:

> 1. Scrolled to bottom of the page after some interval if the user hasn't scrolled.
> 2. Stop scrolling if the user has scrolled.
> 3. Starts scrolling to bottom of page if user reaches a div `#end`

```
<script>
    var scroll = 1;
    function autoScrolling(scroll) {
    if(scroll==1){
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    }
    window.onscroll = function() {
    setInterval(autoScrolling(0), 1000);
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      var elementTarget = document.getElementById("end");
      if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
          scroll=1;
         setInterval(autoScrolling(0), 1000);
      }
    });
    </script>
```

I am applying this logic but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    var scrolled = false;

 $(document).ready(function(){

       //First requirement
       window.setInterval(function(){
          checkScroll();
        }, 5000);

         //Second requirement
        window.onscroll = function() { setScroll()};

         //Third requirement
        $('#end').on('scroll', function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                autoScroll();
            }
        })
})

function autoScroll(){
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function setScroll(){
      if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
          scroll=true;
      }
    }
}

function checkScroll(){
    if(!scrolled) 
        autoScroll();
    scrolled = false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by third condition?

Comment: @imanshu15 op has clearly mentioned 'Starts scrolling to bottom of page if user reaches a div #end"

Comment: @priyaverma i did not see that, sorry. I have updated the code. Check that if its working